# Event sourcing: in-memory read model, does it make sense to apply events during read?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I'm working on an application that uses event sourcing for storing data. For many reasons a persisted read model is not used, therefore we need to implement an in-memory read approach.

The idea is that some data from an aggregate should be read with the current date, but also with past dates. Therefore the approach I'm thinking is to process all the events of that aggregate and `Apply` the event in the aggregate in order to have the state at the specified date.

But, I'm reading in various articles that the `Apply` method should only be used when the command is emittend and not during the reading phase.

Does it make sense to use the `Apply` method during the reading phase? Or maybe the same logic should be replicated in a different method (some sort of processor)?

I'm not posting any code here because what I'm looking for is to understand what the right approach should be and to understand better how to user Event Sourcing.

Comment: "readng in various articles" -- can you provide links?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason basically all the articles I've read states that, while they provide different approaches for creating read models

Comment: So you basically need to read the aggregate's state, right?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yew basically I need to read the aggregate state to extract some properties. Do you think reading the aggregate during the read phase is a correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is necessarily the case that the `Apply` method may only be called when emitting events.  If the purpose of the `Apply` method is to *load* the event into the aggregate then it will be invoked when restoring the aggregate to its current state.

It seems as though you need processing for your aggregate that would represent it for some window period (start/end date).  It *may* be more appropriate to create a read model that represents the bits that you are interested in and store them as time-sensitive data and then rather query *that*.

If the processing is too intensive you may even want to issue a command that *requests* a report or view of sorts but that would *still* work through the time-sensitive read model and then produces the required output.  Once done the user can be notified that the results are ready for perusal.

As @Constantin Galbenu stated: you should avoid your aggregate's internal state and this ties in with not querying your domain model.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the best option. At the end the Apply method should never be called outside the command stack, therefore in some cases I should send a command that generate the result I'm looking for applying events and then notify the user. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Reading the *internal* and *private* state of an aggregate should be avoided as it break it's encapsulation. Also, an Aggregate stores whatever state it needs in order to check for its invariants and querying that state would force the Aggregate to maintain additional state that it is not needed.

In conclusion, avoid reading the write side.

Comment: You are right, exposing the internal and private state of the aggregate should be avoided. Thanks